# Можно ли убрать в url номер страницы при пагинации? codeigniter 3

Tags: javascript, php, mysqli, codeigniter, пагинация

Товарищи использую Codeignier для создание системы теста. Когда возник вопрос сделать каждый вопрос на отдельную страницу, решил использовать пагинацию в codeigniter. Мне хочется сделать чтоб когда тест проходишь, не было хода назад. Но вот только с url проблемы, если менять его, то можно свободно гулять по тесту.

http://localhost:8012/online-test/Welcome/profession/design/1

design/1  цифра номер страницы. А можно ли сделать, так, номер страницы в url не показывался?

Comment: 1. Можно на ajax пагинацию сделать. 2. Либо через POST передавать страницу.

Comment: Полностью поддерживаю сказанное выше